# Deleting duplicate words in a column of excel cells

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I need to get rid of words that are duplicated within a column of spreadsheet cells.

I can use Excel or OpenOffice as I have both.

I want to get rid of the any duplicated words within a cell  ... for instance ... happy, sad, fun, happy, silly, sad, jokey, - would become - happy, sad, fun, silly, jokey, (duplicate words removed.)

I would need a step by step guide on how to create a macro and apply it to the column of offending cells! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried researching?

Comment: That was quick! Thanks for your informative answer! Yes I have! I have been on google all afternoon and eventually decided on asking some experts if they could help as what I tried didn't work! Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmmn ... I typed in the solution you gave and it doesn't seem to work? Weird. Anyone else have any good advice? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have comma separated values within a single cell?? Like **happy,sad,happy** within cell **A1**

Comment: Maybe letting use know that you have, would of been nice! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried besides google?  What results have you obtained? Does your cell contain strings of comma-separated words like you have shown?  Or something else?  Where do you want the results to show up?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for getting back to me. Yes ... what follows is and actual example of eveything in a cell. (although this one doesn't have any duplicates i dont think!)

Comment: 139bpm, Takeaway Menu, 1990s, 2000s, 2010s, cuba, cuban, latin, accordion, crazy, wild, manic, odd, busy, drunk, colourful, holiday, vacation, bouncy, cheerful, cheery, chipper, chirpy, lively, perky, peppy, sparky, upbeat, living it up, full of beans, effervescent, fizzing, full of fun, fun, amusing, enjoy, enjoyable, entertain, entertaining, lively, merry, cheerful, cheering, engaging, humorous, humour, jocular, witty, party, partying, life and soul, quirky, left field, odd, off the wall, out of the ordinary, peculiar, outre,

Comment: Just to note - I am not familiar with using macros and am not an excel expert. Hence why I have ended up here. If anyone would like me to copy and paste the code that i discovered I can do so ... but I have no idea how to implement it. If any one can help then thanks. If not, then thanks but no need to answer. Cheers.

Comment: In your last example, the word 'fun' is a duplicated word.  Are you sure you want to remove duplicated words?  Or is what you want to remove duplicated "phrases" where you have a sequence of comma-delimited strings to be considered as phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to process and run the following simple macro:

```
Sub CellKleaner()
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range, v As String
    Dim v2 As String
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, ",") > 0 Then
            Set c = New Collection
            ary = Split(v, ",")
            v2 = ary(0)
            c.Add ary(0), CStr(ary(0))
            For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
                On Error Resume Next
                c.Add ary(i), CStr(ary(i))
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Number = 0
                    On Error Resume Next
                Else
                    v2 = v2 & "," & ary(i)
                End If
            Next i
            r.Value = v2
            Set c = Nothing
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table can be used to remove duplicates between cells:

[image]